# How do i float half of the text to the left and the other to the right inside a p tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph inside the `p` tag and want to make the top half floating to the right and the bottom half to the left. Is there a property code I can use to do this inside the `p` tag or do I have to create a new `id` selector tag to do this?

Comment: How do you define what the top "half" vs the bottom "half" is? By letter/word/sentance/etc? It sounds like you'll need to use more than one tag for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS3's Multiple Column Layout

```
p{
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/0k3nnpas/

to get the bottom column on the left add

```
p{
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  direction:rtl;
  text-align:left;
}
```

Note: CSS3 Columns are IE10+ see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/ for more details

Comment: I don't think this meets the criteria. OP wants the top half on the right and the bottom half on the left. This is the reverse of that.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible instead of having it separated by halves i could just decide which line i want it separated?

Comment: You would need to add extra elements to have that control and if your adding extra elements you may aswell use CSS Floats p > div.floatleft{float:left;width:50%;} p > div.floatright{float:right;width:50%;}

Comment: So i have to use 2 div tags to separate specific lines of text? I was hoping i didn't need to create a new id selector tag and could just use a property tag inside my existing p tag to make the process easier so i don't have to retype code for the new div. Thanks anyway